# ChartJs canvas showing previous graph when changing Graph types

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I came across a unique incident in which when a user chooses from a drop down and the graph changes if you scan across the canvas the previous will show up like a ghost in the background. I know you can use something like graph.destroy() but I am not sure if that is appropriate and where to put it.

**code where I update graphs**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width = 600;
    ctx.canvas.height = 200;

    function updateChart() {
        //  ctx.canvas.destroy();
        var determineChart = $("#chartType").val();

        var params = dataMapMain[determineChart];
        if ([params.method] == "Pie") {
            document.getElementById("subOption").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("arrowId").hidden = false;

    var determineChart = $("#subOption").val();
            var params = dataMapSub[determineChart];
            $('#subOption').on('change', updateChart);

            new Chart(ctx)[params.method](params.data, options, {});

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("subOption").hidden = true;
            document.getElementById("arrowId").hidden = true;
            new Chart(ctx)[params.method](params.data, options, {});
        }
    }

    $('#chartType').on('change', updateChart)
    updateChart();
```

[image]

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/75g2bys6/) demonstrates the issue, hover over the chart to see the "*ghost*".

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: too man libraries, attached gif to show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are not destroying the instances of `Chart` that you are no longer using, chartjs is drawing multiple charts into the same canvas context.

You need to have a reference of the `Chart` instances you `new` up to be able to call `destroy` on them before you `new` up another one.

Add this to your code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width = 600;
    ctx.canvas.height = 200;

var chart; // assign your chart reference to this variable

function updateChart() {
    var determineChart = $("#chartType").val();

    var params = dataMapMain[determineChart];
    if ([params.method] == "Pie") {
        document.getElementById("subOption").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("arrowId").hidden = false;

var determineChart = $("#subOption").val();
        var params = dataMapSub[determineChart];
        $('#subOption').on('change', updateChart);

        chart && chart.destroy(); // destroy previous chart
        chart = new Chart(ctx)[params.method](params.data, options, {});

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("subOption").hidden = true;
        document.getElementById("arrowId").hidden = true;

        chart && chart.destroy(); // destroy previous chart
        chart = new Chart(ctx)[params.method](params.data, options, {});
    }
}

$('#chartType').on('change', updateChart)
updateChart();
```

And here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/75g2bys6/1/) that demonstrates the fix.

Comment: Your answer was perfect! I do have one question however. I have data now coming through a Websocket on Pub/Sub model so it automatically every few seconds updates the chart with the same chart Type and I am encountering the same issue with the "Ghost"

Comment: @user2402107 this should work even if you are updating the chart's every few seconds. Just remember to destroy your chart before creating new ones. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/75g2bys6/2/) demonstrates it working even when data is being changed every second or two.